# Efficient SQL -combining repetitive queries in one

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I want to get some numbers and their sum should be greater than zero between the following timelines: Day-7>0 and Day-14>0 and Day-21>0. I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to combine the 3 sql statements into one single 
call more efficiently?

```
SELECT DISTINCT NUMBER FROM (
   SELECT    NUMBER,SUM(DATA) DATA
   FROM TABLEA
   WHERE
      DATEID >= TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-7,'YYYYMMDD'))
   GROUP BY VF_NUMBER
   HAVING SUM(DATA) > 0

AND

SELECT    NUMBER,SUM(DATA) DATA
FROM TABLEA
WHERE
    DATEID >= TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-14,'YYYYMMDD'))
GROUP BY VF_NUMBER
HAVING SUM(DATA) > 0

AND

SELECT    NUMBER,SUM(DATA) DATA
FROM TABLEA
WHERE
    DATEID >= TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-21,'YYYYMMDD'))
GROUP BY VF_NUMBER
HAVING SUM(DATA) > 0

)
```

Comment: Whats the problem using Union All and joining the queries in a single one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually >7 , >14 , >21 = >7 isn't it?

Following should work:

I have edited response as per OP's comment

```
SELECT VF_NUMBER
FROM 
(SELECT  VF_NUMBER,
         SUM(CASE WHEN DATEID >= TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-7,'YYYYMMDD'))  THEN DATA ELSE 0 END) GREATER_7,
         SUM(CASE WHEN DATEID >= TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-14,'YYYYMMDD'))  THEN DATA ELSE 0 END) GREATER_14, 
         SUM(CASE WHEN DATEID >= TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-21,'YYYYMMDD'))  THEN DATA ELSE 0 END) GREATER_21, 
  NUMBER,SUM(DATA) DATA
FROM TABLEA
WHERE DATEID >= TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-7,'YYYYMMDD'))
GROUP BY VF_NUMBER)
WHERE GREATER_7>0
AND GREATER_14>0
AND GREATER_21>0
```

Comment: Ideally yes, but there could exist a scenario that no data was recorded in any one of the past weeks, e.g. in which case >7 would have values but >14 to 21 may have no activity recorded in data column so those numbers are to be excluded. :/

Comment: Can you please edit your question with sample data and desired output please.

Comment: Thanks @Bhavesh Ghodasara !

Answer (score 0):

- SYSDATE-21 covers all other periods.
- I assume NUMBER should be replaced with VF_NUMBER.

---

```
SELECT    VF_NUMBER
FROM TABLEA
WHERE
    DATEID >= TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-21,'YYYYMMDD'))
GROUP BY VF_NUMBER
HAVING SUM(DATA) > 0
```